# Windows Media Player not correctly copying Japanese text in track information when ripping DVDs

Tags: dvd, mp3, windows-media-player, ripping, japanese

I'm ripping some DVDs I bought lately. When the track contains only English text in places like "Album" and "Artists", everything gets ripped nicely. But when there's Japanese text, it gets copied as question marks for each character. It's rather tedious to manually copy the info by hand after the ripping finishes.

Interestingly, the file and folder names manage to retain the Japanese text correctly, so it's just the track details that get messed up.

Is this a known problem, is there anyway to fix this? Maybe it's related to the encoding used when ripping? Tried to find an option but couldn't find any.

#### Example:

The album information inside the DVD:

[image: img1]

The details of the track after ripping:

[image: img2]

Folder name above has been preserved. Album details get copied incorrectly.

Comment: What kind of tags are being assigned? ID3? Sounds like they can't handle whatever encoding the Japanese characters use. You probably need to consider using something that can understand the correct unicode characters.

Comment: Tags? I'm not sure what you mean. But I did try another software and it was worse. I'm open to other software, but I can't just start installing all that I find. I was hoping someone might have faced this and reached a solution.